# Ubuntu 18.4 Intel graphic card selected and verified still nvidia won't turn off

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 18.04, nvidia-optimus

Ubuntu 18.4, Lenovo Ideapad Z570, Hybrid GPU

Nvidia Geforce -> Proprietary Driver Installed version 390.

I am able to switch between Intel and nvidia card using *prime-select*  and *Nvidia X Server* Settings. **When I switch to intel, the system do use intel but, the nvidia card will still be ON all the time.**

I tried bbswitch-dkms and edited the grub but no luck.

Since I got this laptop I have never been able to turn nvidia OFF while using linux. please help

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this issue.
What helped me to turn off the nvidia card is:

sudo sh -c 'echo auto > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control'

but this is only a solution until the next reboot.

Cheers